# How to get online users using pusher

Tags: pusher

I am developing chat application using Pusher. As of now whenever user logs in into his account, he is subscribed to a channel like below:

```
`var channel = pusher.subscribe('<?='myChannel'.$_SESSION['USERID']?>');`
```

I would like to update the status in chat list for online/offline so that other users can get to know whether user is online or not. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use [presence channels](https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_presence_channels) for this. These channels have special events which are broadcast to all other subscribers when a members subscribes/unsubscribes from the channel.

It looks like you have a channel per user, so this wouldn't work by simply converting the existing channels to presence channels. Instead you could have a special presence channel in addition to the per-user channels that all users subscribe to. Here you can bind to presence events and update the members list.

Comment: Yes, I did the same. I used presence channel as 
`var presenceChannel = pusher.subscribe('presence-myChannel');
var count = presenceChannel.members.count;`
But now I am getting count as 0. How can I get exact count and Online/Offline status?

Comment: You might be getting the count too soon. You should wait until the subscription has succeeded. There is an example of how to do this [here](https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_presence_channels#example-1).